# Dual monitor gnome-shell broke itself

Tags: 12.04, ati, gnome

Ok, lets get this over with.

I have a dual-monitor, ati setup on `gnome-shell` that was just fine until this morning.

Then, this happened.

[image: Goodness me]

Look closer...

[image: Seeing double]

[image: Look closely]

Whatever has happened to my ubuntu setup? My second monitor still works, entirely normally, with the exception that I cannot (obviously) access activities (as i am in `gnome-fallback` ). I do wish to resume my work...

**EDIT**: By entirely normally, I mean I can move my mouse over it and have seperate windows on it and stuff. It's not mirroring.

**UPDATE**: Unity works entirely normally.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was solved, but I had very close to the same problem (except for me, Unity wouldn't start either). The trick was to delete xorg.conf:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And then re-install xorg:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Nvidia graphics? Start up `nvidia-settings` and go to X Server Display Configuration. Enable TwinView, apply and save to X Configuration File. Restart the computer and it should work.

Comment: I'm using the open-source ati drivers. (Because my card is ATI.)